How I can redirect the input from one mic to another mic input?
I have 2 computers connected to each other with a sound card so I can hear the input or output from both computers from main computer.
I manage with Voicemeeter to hear the sound from computer2 in computer1 but now I want that every time I say something in mic1 of computer1 it hears as mic input of computer2. But I cannot find a proper solution to work with it.
Is this possible?

Welcome to SuperUser! What are you using to physically connect your mic to computer 1? 3.5mm, XLR, USB...?

Easiest solution, buy a 3.5mm jack splitter cable, 1 female to 2 males and a 3.5mm jack extension cord (optionally a 2nd one), and actually connect the microphone to both computers at once.
Lowest possible latency, no software problems, most freedom in terms of configuration. These cables are usually cheap too.
You would wire it up as follows:
[mic] -> splitter cable 
             -> [PC1]
             -> extension cord -> [PC2]

or
[mic] -> splitter cable 
             -> extension cord -> [PC1]
             -> extension cord -> [PC2]


OP hasn't specified a 3.5mm mic- could be USB input

@bertieb that's true. We'll have to wait for OP to respond to your question then...
